# How can I get zsh's completion working in the middle of the filename?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

### This works

Normally, `zsh`'s tab completion works well.

```
$ touch foo-1-bar foo-2-bar
$ touch f<Tab>
$ touch foo--bar
            ^ cursor here
```

Pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again brings up a menu from which I can select files.

```
$ touch foo--bar
foo-1-bar  foo-2-bar
```

### This doesn't

However, this doesn't seem to work with strings where the beginning and end match. For example:

```
touch foo-bar foo-foo-bar
touch f<Tab>
touch foo-bar
         ^ cursor here. <tab> again.
touch foo-bar
              ^ cursor here.
```

No menu is brought up, and there is no opportunity to select `foo-foo-bar`. Is this expected behaviour or a bug? Is there a setting to make a menu appear in the latter scenario?

I'm using `oh-my-zsh`. I attempted removing all the completion-related lines from `~/.zshrc`, but this made no difference.

Comment: Remove `oh-my-zsh`, in `.zshrc` put `autoload -U compinit && compinit; zstyle ':completion:*' menu select`.

Comment: Hm, that seems to work. I only need to remove the line sourcing `oh-my-zsh`, the second line is not necessary. Is there a way to make completion work without removing `oh-my-zsh`?

Comment: Why do you need this oh-crap?

Comment: I… don't know. I just started using `zsh`, and many tutorials suggest `oh-my-zsh`. FWIW I like the [prompt](https://github.com/jeremyFreeAgent/oh-my-zsh-powerline-theme) that I've picked. I presume that may be workable without `oh-my-zsh` though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the comments, I tried disabling `oh-my-zsh`, which fixed this problem. I then went through the `oh-my-zsh` source, selectively disabling modules.

I previously had `CASE_SENSITIVE="true"`, but commenting out this line fixed it for me. Apparently it's a [known bug](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/issues/1398).

To fix it, I could put the following line in `~/.zshrc` after sourcing `oh-my-zsh`.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*'
```

Comment: Oh-My-Zsh is a bloated ratmangle; removing it entirely would be the only sensible approach.

Comment: @jasonwryan That seems to be the general opinion here! In particular, this bug had a simple proposed fix from three years ago, but was then closed for some unknown reason by the developer. And the number of *open* issues (many unreplied) is impressive. I'll take yours and jimmij's advice and look to customise `zsh` myself. (FWIW the "bloatedness" doesn't seem to affect my performance, but I'm more worried about bugs introduced by oh-my-zsh.

Comment: @Sparhawk, this not always works for me. Can you help please? [I have details here.](https://github.com/zimfw/zimfw/issues/212#issuecomment-387524321)

Answer (score 4):

Personally, I prefer this solution much more - http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq04.html#l50,
It works like completion in tcsh, and completes words, that are before cursor only.

Just use

```
    bindkey '\CI' expand-or-complete-prefix
```

instead of

```
    bindkey '\CI' expand-or-complete
```

(Which is by default).

Comment: I'm now using zim, so I can't really confirm this. However, thanks for posting, and welcome to U/L! (Have an upvote to help get you past the initial limitations.)

Comment: This works great, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another option is setting COMPLETE_IN_WORD as described on the same page - http://zsh.sourceforge.net/FAQ/zshfaq04.html#l50.

```
setopt complete_in_word
```

This will try to fill in the word at the point of the cursor, and all the characters after the point of the cursor will be replaced with what is filled.