zsh auto completion of cp options doesn't list all of them
I've been working on setting my autocmp following this guide https://thevaluable.dev/zsh-install-configure-mouseless/. I'm on a MacOS environment but for some reason when I try to autocomplete options it doesn't list the complete set of options. This is my config for autocomplete:
#Completion
autoload -Uz compinit
compinit
zmodload zsh/complist
#Amazing article https://thevaluable.dev/zsh-install-configure-mouseless/
zstyle ':completion:*' completer _extensions _complete _approximate
zstyle ':completion:*' menu select
zstyle ':completion:*' file-sort modification
zstyle ':completion:*:*:*:*:descriptions' format '%F{green}-- %d --%f'
zstyle ':completion:*' complete-options true
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list 'r:|=*' 'l:|=* r:|=*' #https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/259511
zstyle ':completion:*' verbose yes
zstyle ':completion:*' group-name ''
zstyle ':completion:*' list-colors 'di=34:fi=31:no=33;00'
# zstyle ':completion:*' file-list all #Unfortunetly this messes up colouring
#Move with VIM keys Autocompletion
bindkey '^[[Z' reverse-menu-complete
bindkey -M menuselect 'h' vi-backward-char
bindkey -M menuselect 'k' vi-up-line-or-history
bindkey -M menuselect 'l' vi-forward-char
bindkey -M menuselect 'j' vi-down-line-or-history

When I try to autocomplete options for builtin shell commands I get the following:
❯ cp -
-- option --
-H  -- follow symlinks on the command line in recursive mode
-L  -- follow all symlinks in recursive mode
-P  -- do not follow symlinks in recursive mode (default)
-R  -- copy directories recursively
-X  -- don\'t copy extended attributes or resource forks
-a  -- archive mode, same as -RpP
-f  -- force overwriting existing file
-i  -- confirm before overwriting existing file
-n  -- don\'t overwrite existing file
-p  -- preserve timestamps, mode, owner, flags, ACLs, and extended attributes
-v  -- show file names as they are copied

I would expect to get the complete list of cp options as per the article. Is this possibly a MacOs issue for completion for zsh?

https://thevaluable.dev/zsh-install-configure-mouseless/#zsh-completion-system shows a list of completions for the GNU implementation of cp, while you're on macos whose cp has far fewer options.

If you look at the code of the zsh completer for the cp command, you'll see it adapts the list of options based on the OS it's running on, except it also detects whether you're using the GNU implementation (which can be used on many different systems, being portable and Free Software) as different OSes come with different cp implementations.
As it happens, macos' own cp has far fewer options than the GNU implementation of cp.
zsh's cp completer doesn't know of all the options of all the versions of all the different implementations of cp but for a given OS would usually offer enough of the most commonly used one.
In any case, to find out about the options supported by your own implementation of cp, best is to read its documentation¹.

¹ Or its source code for those that make it available as some options are sometimes undocumented (though that usually mean that you're not encouraged to use them).

Thanks! Makes a ton of sense. Cp is a particular example of a command that has few options. grep has a lot more options listed on it's man pages but shows fewer on completion. I will go ahead and check out how the zsh completion system does it.
